# Search an entire DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame with similar values. The significance is which Column the value is located. (Main DataFrame)

values=[('12345', '23456', '34567', '45678'),
('56789', '67890', '789102', '854695'),
('221155','5968', '55-BP', '69853')]

label=['column A', 'column B', 'column C', 'column D']

main_df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(values, columns=label)

I am looking for a method to pass a list of values to search the entire DataFrame and get the Column. (List)
list = ('56789', 55-BP)

```
(Output DataFrame)
Val 1 | Column A  
Val 2 | Column C
```

If it is easier I can Transpose the axis and get the Index.

```
Val 1 | Index A  
Val 2 | Index x
```

I would really like to use a Python List (not have to type in a comma separated list)

Thank You

Comment: Can you include sample inputs and expected outputs in this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stack()` is a useful function in DataFrame

```
values=[('12345', '23456', '34567', '45678'),
('56789', '67890', '789102', '854695'),
('221155','5968', '55-BP', '69853')]

label=['column A', 'column B', 'column C', 'column D']

main_df=pd.DataFrame.from_records(values, columns=label)

list = ['56789', '55-BP']

#####

main_df.stack().reset_index(level=[0,1]).set_index(0).loc[list]
```

gets

```
level_0 level_1
0       
56789   1   column A
55-BP   2   column C
```

`level_0` is the index you need, `level_1` is the columns you need.